# QT - Считывание чисел из ввода пользователя

Tags: c++, qt, int

Надо, чтобы программа брала значение из ввода пользователя в текстовые поля. Перелазил уже весь интернет (может, плохо искал :) ), но так и не нашёл, как это сделать.
`int b = ui->cb->text();` - не работает. Ошибка - *"No member named 'text' in QTextEdit'"*.
`int a = ui->ca->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^([1-9][0-9]*|0)"), this));` - тоже не работает.
Версия QT вроде последняя.

Comment: извините что не могу ответить ибо уже давно запомятовал. Но есть предложение посмотреть как сделано у Макса Шлее. Также у меня в вопросах по моему что то похожее было

Comment: макс шлее qt 5.10 профессиональное программирование (есть более старые версии которые можно скачать в интернете)

Comment: Попробуй calculatorbuilder пример он есть в 5qt, тебе надо вывести `ui_outputWidget->setText(QString::number(value + ui_inputSpinBox1->value()));`  вот мы ввели в два спинбокса по числу а QLabel  (ui_outputWidget) это всё вывел

Comment: Вот так 
 `ui->textEdit->setText(QString::number(ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt()  + ui->lineEdit->text().toInt()));`

Comment: @timob256, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Я, видимо, тупой, но что мне вписывать вместо value и ui_inputSpinBox1? :)

Comment: ui(точка)предложит список накиданных вами на виджете элементов ввода , после этого выбираете элемент ввода  (если это спинбокс то нажимете точку и выбираете value() "значение" если текстовый ввод  то ввыбираете текст() и привращаете его в инт )

Comment: Также предложу скачать книгу ознакомиться с примерами из неё она достаточно удобная и именно с таких примеров и начинает своё знакомство , просто после понимания парадигмы (организации ) Qt всё встанет на свои места.

Comment: https://b-ok.cc/book/3605415/58957c

Comment: Также прошу предоставь пожалуйста весь код проекта,  можешь даже залить на диск и скинуть ссылкой, тогда возможно будет проще помочь. Либо просто скопируй кусок кода который тебя тревожит и опиши элементы накиданные на виджете и что они должны делать.

Comment: Да там код, помимо шаблона самого QT, 3 строчки, которые как раз и не работают, поэтому смысла нет) Спасибо, я обязательно скачаю и прочту книгу, которую вы прислали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй calculatorbuilder пример он есть в 5qt, тебе надо вывести `ui_outputWidget->setText(QString::number(value + ui_inputSpinBox1->value()));` вот мы ввели в два спинбокса по числу а QLabel (ui_outputWidget) это всё вывел

Вот так `ui->textEdit->setText(QString::number(ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt()  + ui->lineEdit->text().toInt()));`